# Why am I unable to include vectors?

Tags: c++, netbeans

Very basic question.  I'm working through 'Accelerated C++', however I cannot continue.  My code for the current exercise is as follows:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x;
    vector<double> quartiles;
    cin >> x;
    quartiles.push_back((double)x);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem arises that... something, I'm unsure whether it is Netbeans (v7.3.1) or the compiler (Cygwin_4.x), doesn't recognize the vector class.  I had used the class in the chapter's example, however it does not recognize it in this file.

What I have tried is saving and building the project, as well as deleting the file and recreating it in case it was somehow something I typed in, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Edit: Fixed typo where push_back() was being called on vector instead of quartiles.

Edit2: Was a problem with the IDE (NetBeans) rather than the compiler.

Comment: Please post the exact error.

Comment: What does "doesn't recognise the file" mean? A compile error? How are you compiling it? Have you save it as a .cpp file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about underlined `vector` with red color - that's a famous NetBeans problem which I suffer as well. One solution is to  click `project context menu -> code assistance -> reparse project` . The code itself (after your edit) is a valid C++ code and compiler will treat it absolutely fine if you try to compile it.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!
Edit: Says I need to wait before I can say I have an answer to this question. Will mark as such as soon as I am allowed.

Comment: Riunix, you can also upvote answers if they are helpful to you)

Comment: Only once I have 15 reputation. I currently have 13.
Edit: Just reached that 15rep threshold, have an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `push_back` on a `vector` instance.  So

```
vector.push_back((double)x);
```

should be

```
quartiles.push_back((double)x);
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the typo, however the vector class is still not being recognized.

Comment: The code compiles and runs for me once the typo is corrected.  Can you edit your question to include a copy of the (compiler?) error message you see?

Comment: @simonc, see my answer, that was the problem. There is no error messages there - just red underlined `vector` token.

Comment: @sasha.sochka Thanks, +1, does that mean that this is an intellisense problem and the code was fine all along?

Comment: @sasha.sochka I would edit the question to indicate the problem was with Netbeans instead of a compiler problem.